# ZIP a group of files in node without storing in memory

Tags: node.js

I'm looking for a solution to zip up a large amount of files (around 45GB collectively) without storing them in memory, I've been looking for nodejs libraries to do this, but none seem to have this feature.

All the files are stored in a single directory.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do it without using computer's memory, but you can limit the amount of memory required for operation, using NodeJS buffers and steams. This concept is essential for good performance in NodeJS and it is not limited only to reading files and creating archives, but I won't go into details.

Here are two **NPM** packages which will help you with your issue:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/zip-stream and https://github.com/antelle/node-stream-zip

Comment: I don't know about zip-stream but node-stream-zip does not look like it supports adding to zip.

To be honest neither zip-stream looks like it support adding to zip.